# Android: Updating TextView/ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, imageview

In my Android application I am displaying an image & text on the main activity, switching to another activity (killing the main activity), and then switching back to the main activity but adding a new image and text pulled from flash.

On start-up my activity works as intended, but when I switch from my main activity to another activity, then come back to the main one no image or text is shown.

I tried to invalidate() the text and image but seems to still not be showing any image/text.

**Edit:**

I can go from Page_Activity to Gallery_Activity, but when I try to go back to Page_Activity from Gallery_Activity I can't change any of the ImageViews/TextViews that are defined in the XML.

I provided the relevant code for switching between activities below.

```
private void display_page(int pg_num)
        {
            image_overlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas_width, canvas_height,  Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image_overlay);

            int yCo = 0;
            for(int yCount=0; yCount<num_y_tiles; yCount++){
                int xCo = 0;
                for(int xCount=0; xCount<num_x_tiles; xCount++){    

                        //code to get bufferedimage from flash (works)

                        old_tiles[xCount][yCount] = bufferedimage;

                        canvas.drawBitmap(old_tiles[xCount][yCount], xCo, yCo, null);   


                    xCo += TILE_WIDTH;
               }
                yCo+= TILE_HEIGHT;
            }   
            imageview_overlay.setImageBitmap(image_overlay);
            imageview_overlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageview_overlay.invalidate();

            textview_page_number.setText("Page " + page_number);
            textview_page_number.invalidate();  
    }




/*
*Inside the click listener to go to Gallery_Activity
*/

                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Gallery_Activity.class);
                boolean is_books_empty = true;
                            String[] stringArray; 

                ArrayList<Integer> images = new ArrayList<Integer>();

                int number =  R.drawable.gallery_book1; 

                for(int i=0; i<stringArray.length; i++){
                    images.add(i, R.drawable.gallery_book1);
                }


                intent.putExtra("StringArray", );
                intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("BookImages", images);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish(); 


public class Gallery_Activity extends Activity{
      public String[] names;
      public ArrayList<Integer> images;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);
        images = getIntent().getIntegerArrayListExtra("BookImages");
        names = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("StringArray");

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter (new ImageAdapter(this, names, images));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                 Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Page_Activity.class);
                    String book_names = names[position];                    
                    intent.putExtra("BookName", book_names);
                    startActivity(intent);


           }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Show some code. Btw, you are not killing an Activity just because you open another one (assuming you are not calling finish();)

Comment: You can if you have the developer options set (Don't keep activities)

Comment: Post your code please. Help us to help you.

Comment: Added some code above

Comment: It seems right. I'm not a graphics person. Have you tried any other force drawing methods? 
postInvalidate()   requestLayout()